# JQuery Validation does not work if the user has entered blank spaces or line breaks

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have the following TinyMCE editor. The client side validation triggers when the user tries to submit the form without filling anything in.

However the validation does not work if the user has entered blank spaces or line breaks.

How can I trigger client side validation in this type of scenario aswell?

Currently my form looks like this:

**ViewModel:**

```
 [Required]
 public string Comments { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
<form id="tinymceform">
  <div class="tinymceholder">
     @Html.TextArea("Comments", null, new { id = "mytextarea" })
     @Html.ValidationMessage("Comments")
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The above is rendered as follows:

```
<textarea name="Comments" id="mytextarea" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Comments field is required." aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="Comments-error"></textarea>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Comments" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
         selector: '#mytextarea'
    });

    if ($(".tinymceholder").length === 0) {
        return;
    }else {

        $.validator.setDefaults({
             ignore: []
        });
    }
</script>
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.?

```
 $('#tinymceform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var content = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent({ format: 'text' });

    if ($.trim(content) === '') {
        $('#tinymceform').validate().showErrors({
            "Comments": "This field cannot be empty"
        }););
    }

    if (!$('#tinymceform').valid()) return false;

    this.submit();

});
```

Comment: There's a normalizer built into the plugin that will trim whitespace.  However, I do not know how you would implement this within your framework.  https://jqueryvalidation.org/normalizer/

Comment: Your attempted solution cannot work as it's attempting to do something the jQuery Validate plugin is already doing for you... blocking the default submit in order to do validation.  You'll have to work within the confines of your framework and its plugins.

Comment: I think it seems your best bet would be to write your own custom method to replace `required`.

Comment: @Sparky the validation is working for other fields, it just doesn't seem to  display the error for this particular field when I apply showErrors() method. Maybe becuase it already has one required rule.

Comment: @sparky whats the correct syntax to apply the normalizer to a single field?

Comment: The correct syntax is shown in the documentation that I linked to.  However, since you're using ASP, presumably you're also using the Unobtrusive Validation plugin.  If that's the case, you cannot do anything that goes inside of the `rules` object of the `.validate()` method since the Unobtrusive plugin automatically constructs this all for you.

Answer (score 0):

First: Get rid of the jQuery validator.

Second: Acompany your [Required] annotation with this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\S*$", ErrorMessage = "No white space allowed")]
```

You should be good to go.